# HTTrack Cookies Works for First Level Only

Tags: linux, html, cookies, httrack

Have been playing around the tool HTTrack and trying to mirror a website. The website has a home page that require simple username password login. I have successfully downloaded the authenticated **cookies.txt** needed to pass through the login page. With these options `-%v -n -s0`, I managed to mirror everything within the authenticated home page. But then there are tabs within the home page like: `<a href="/homepage/config.navlink.tablink">Config</a>`. All these tabs remains unauthenticated, and HTTrack copied an unauthenticated login page for these tablinks for me instead. It looks like to me that the **cookies.txt** didn't get apply to deeper links.

`Home Page`(Authenticated and Everything mirrored) --> `tablinks` in Home Page --> `Login Page`(unanthenticated, cookies.txt doesn't work)

Tried with options `-Y` and tried including `+*.tablink` for wildcard option.